# execute bat with java program in task scheduler fail

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I have the following script, which works fine if executed manually, but does not work if set as a task in the task scheduler.

I suspected a parameter may not be set correctly, but cannot spot it. Could someone please help me with that.

```batch-file
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

cls

set AllSections=
Set Action=

rem set PARMS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsikuli.FromCommandLine
rem set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202
rem set SIKULIX_HOME=%~dp0

set CurrentDate=%Date%
set CurrentTime=%Time: =0%
set CurrentTime=%CurrentTime:~0,8%
set DateTimeStamp=%CurrentDate:~6,4%-%CurrentDate:~3,2%-%CurrentDate:~0,2%_%CurrentTime:~0,2%-%CurrentTime:~3,2%-%CurrentTime:~6,2%
set FolderTimeStamp=%CurrentDate:~3,2%-%CurrentDate:~6,4%

set DestinationFolder=SCADA\Output\%FolderTimeStamp%\%DateTimeStamp%

md DestinationFolder=SCADA\Output > nul 2>&1
md DestinationFolder=SCADA\Output\%FolderTimeStamp% > nul 2>&1
md DestinationFolder=SCADA\Output\%FolderTimeStamp%\%DateTimeStamp% > nul 2>&1
md DestinationFolder=SCADA\Output\%FolderTimeStamp%\%DateTimeStamp%\Settings > nul 2>&1
md DestinationFolder=SCADA\Output\%FolderTimeStamp%\%DateTimeStamp%\Alarms > nul 2>&1
md DestinationFolder=SCADA\Output\%FolderTimeStamp%\%DateTimeStamp%\Network > nul 2>&1


rem Create Settings file


rem echo "Hello world" > %cd%\aa.txt

rem \\\--below instructions working as script from command prompt , but not from task scheduler

C:\sikulix\sikulixapi-2.0.5-win.jar -r C:\sikulix\Scada\Settings.sikuli
C:\sikulix\sikulixapi-2.0.5-win.jar -r C:\sikulix\Scada\Alarms.sikuli
C:\sikulix\sikulixapi-2.0.5-win.jar -r C:\sikulix\Scada\Networks.sikuli
rem /////


ENDLOCAL
:End
```

I highlighted the bit that does not work; the folders are set correctly, but the java part fails to be executed in the task scheduler.

Comment: Add `set > c:\env.txt` to your script and compare the results when run in the different ways

Comment: Scheduled tasks run under a different user. You can set the user in the task properties. Change it to your own user, if it works - you have a permission issue with one of the files or directories you use.

Comment: "but it does not work" What does this mean exactly? Show the full error message including the full stack trace.

Comment: I mean the script is been executed and all commands are ok but the expected output from the Java section is been skipped when if I run the full script manually its all fine

Comment: I try the solution posted by @zmbq and it worked on my own account. but how can i make the task runnable by different users

Comment: My assumption is that the Scheduled Task is running with ```C:\WINDOWS\System32``` as the current directory. As all of your paths are relative to an unspecified current working directory, those locations cannot be found. The most robust fix is to use fully qualified absolute paths throughout your scripts. Alternatively, just insert a new line to the very beginning of your script, something like this: ```@CD /D "W:\orking\Directory" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF```, or this ```@PushD "W:\orking\Directory" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF```.

Answer (score 0):

The script runs in your account because you have set up Windows such that the file extension `.jar` mapped to the `java` application. If the task scheduler account doesn't map `.jar` to `java` application then it won't work.

Re-write the script to prefix the lines using jars with a valid Java runtime such as `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java` and ensure that JAVA_HOME is defined, or check that the task scheduler account maps `.jar` handling to a suitable JVM. Example:

```
 xyz.jar param1 param2 ...
```

becomes

```
 %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java --class-path xyz.jar param1 param2 ..
```

In Windows Explorer, you can check the mappings with right mouse -> Properties then see "Open with:" field.